# HAPROXY issue while integrating with Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, cors, haproxy

I have 3 system. main in haproxy (that is public) while two other systems where apache server is running. Following is the conf code snippet

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     10000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 10000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  main
   bind *:80

   default_backend             apache
#Log Format
    log-format %ci:%cp_[%t]_%bi:%bp_%s_%{+Q}r_%ST_%Tq/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Tt_%B
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend apache
    balance     roundrobin
    server      apache40 10.11.12.11:80 check
    server      apache41 10.11.12.12:80 check
```

On apache web servers, there is some php code of a website. When I open the website through browser, I got following error (observed via inspect element)

```
Failed to load http://10.11.12.11/main/assets/redis/new5.php?_=1530007431471: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Failed to load http://10.11.12.11/main/assets/redis/new5.php?_=1530007431472: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Same is the problem for font files like below

```
Access to Font at 'http://10.11.12.11/main/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://10.11.12.11/main/assets/fonts/font/nafeesnastaleeqregular1.woff' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://10.11.12.11/main/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://10.11.12.11/main/assets/fonts/font/nafeesnastaleeqregular1.ttf' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Where is the problem. I have search a lot and tried many solution, but noting worked for me. What change should I do in conf if any ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to allow CORS on your apache server.

https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

for more information about CORS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

If you don't access to the server, you can allow it in your browser using an extension such as 'CORS changer' for chrome (which i'm using)

Comment: should I do changes in haproxy conf or apache servers conf ?

Comment: in the apache's conf.

Comment: thanks sir, but still I am facing the problem but now It is just for font files. ( I have updated my question in this context)